# What is the difference CMOS and CCD image sensors? In terms of Infrared spectrum

Tags: infrared, cmos, image-sensor, detector, ccd

- What is the difference between CMOS and CCD image sensor arrays? i.e working principles.  Please consider in infrared spectrum.

  - Which one's fabrication is expensive/ or cheap ?
  - Which one gives higher quality image?
  - which one is preferred for large focal plane array? (i.e : 1024 x 1024 )

Thank you.

Comment: Which part of the infared spectrum (long/short)? Most of the time the responsivity of an image sensor is from the filters on the front. Image quality is vague, are you talking about noise? ISO?

Comment: Hello @laptop2d, Especially for Short-Infrared Spectrum (1-3 micrometer Wavelenght). In fact I want to learn the working principles of CCD and CMOS image array sensors. ( aka. How do CMOS/CCD image array sensor make photon-to-voltage conversion ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teledyne offers a really nice explanation of this [here.](https://www.teledynedalsa.com/imaging/knowledge-center/appnotes/ccd-vs-cmos/)

The short answer (minus any recent developments) is that CCD is probably you're best bet for infrared. Infrared imaging requires a thicker photo absorption layer in your sensor that is most easily achievable with CCD senors. CCD's are in general more costly than CMOS for off the shelf and have higher power requirements.